# Creating a Lite version of an App using Targets

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to create a Lite version of an app, I'm not entirely sure on the process of doing so however. I duplicate the target. Then what? For instance, I changed the name of the duplicated target from AppName Copy, to AppName Lite, and also changed the name of the newly generated plist, however, in products the .app file is still incorrectly named and I can't change it. Is there some sort of official procedure that I could follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change product name for target from Build Settings. Follow this [blog](http://www.codeworth.com/blog/mobile/ios-target-duplication/)

Comment: Absolutely perfect. And there's a link in the blog that leads to distinguishing the app in the code. Fantastic!!